# How do I load a texture from a path in XNA at runtime?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to do a RPG Editor in XNA, the thing is that I need to load the textures from a path written in a XMAL file.

I've done some research, but most of the solutions are changing the content pipeline or simply creating your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("mytexture.jpg");
Texture2D myTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, filestream);
```

[Texture2D.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434103.aspx)

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code (don't have xna installed on this computer).

Comment: Thank you, I only had to change the builder of the FileStream ^^

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I guess he means he had to add a second parameter to the FileStream constructor (probably the FileMode)